# Jasper: Error loading object from file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

First time user of iReport. I added all the required JAR files but keep getting the same error. What to do? The error message is as follows:

```
Exceptionnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file
```

The code that causes the error:

```
    private void btnReportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            String jrxmlFile = "C:\\Users\\Heart\\Desktop\\report1.jrxml";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///database","root","");

            JasperPrint print = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrxmlFile, null, con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception" + e);
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : C:\Users\Heart\Desktop\report1.jrxml at 
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127) at 
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:99) at 
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:272) at 
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:‌​745) at 
    TableExaminee.btnReportActionPerformed(TableExaminee.java:384)
```

Comment: Please provide the *exact* error and stacktrace.

Comment: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : C:\Users\Heart\Desktop\report1.jrxml
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:99)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:272)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
 at TableExaminee.btnReportActionPerformed(TableExaminee.java:384)

Comment: Please edit the question rather than wedge code/config into comments.

Comment: Instead of fillReport method can you try fillReportToFile method.

Comment: @prashantthakre same error sir

Comment: It means report1.jrxml is not valid one. First try with simple valid jrxml.

Comment: I have given the code in below answer please try that one you must have to first compile your jrxml so that it will generate jasper file

Comment: `JasperFillManager#fillReport()` returns an object of type `JasperPrint` so in that case you dont need to cast it may be you have wrong imports

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
 String jrxmlFile = "C:\\Users\\Heart\\Desktop\\report1.jrxml";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///database","root","");
 JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFile);
JasperPrint print = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jrxmlFile, new         HashMap<String, Object> (), con);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint);
```

For more detail visit this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_filling_reports.htm)

Comment: JasperFillManager#fillReport() returns an object of type JasperPrint then why there is a need to cast again?